# ASP.NET MVC UML class diagram design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uml, class-diagram

This is my first attempt in creating an MVC program and my first month using ASP.NET.

So far I understand the basic from MVC framework. The software that I am trying to create is an online application, basically a survey in which the admin is able to modify the questions and members with a login are able to see the results from the survey.

I am currently stuck trying to figure out how my class diagram will look like.
So far the Model interacts with the database and contains the following classes

- DAOSurvey (get and setter for the data)
- SurveyModel (Execute all the queries)
- SurveyQueries (Add and retrieve the results from the survey)
- ISurvey (Interface to communicate with controller)

Now, I know that I need some view classes, it is correct to have a "Loginview" "Adminview" "Membersview" and "Surveyview" ? I should create a class for every asp page in my ASP.NET application?

Finally I need the controller classes, which I am guessing that Admin and Members should be.

I am quite sure about the model side of my class diagram should look like, however, I am lost about how view classes and controller classes should be. Any suggestions?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please google for "mvc uml diagram".

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC you will get features like Login and register automatically if you change the authentication to Individual user account while creating a new project or you can manually change it if you have already created the project.

Here you can create logins for different user roles and then use role based authorization for different controllers.

Comment: Hello abhi, yes I know, my question is related to  documentation more specifically UML class diagram and how they should be included in the controller and view side.